# Change 'ORDER BY' Chain on ActiveRecord Subset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sql-order-by, rails-activerecord

***Background:***

I have `Product` model which includes 4 categories

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum category: [:recent, :cheapest, :most_expensive, :popular]
end
```

I've implemented a custom `ORDER BY` for each category with pagination (`LIMIT 10`), so when I'm getting products list, I'm getting multiple `SQL` queries with different `ORDER BY` in each query like this:

**recent:**
`SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 10`

**cheapest:**`SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."price" ASC LIMIT 10`

**most_expensive:** `SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."price" DESC LIMIT 10`

**popular:** `SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."popularity" DESC, "products"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 10`

So as mentioned, each of the above queries, results a `Product::ActiveRecord_Relation` contains 10 products with different order for each query.

***Question:***

I've added new column to `Product` model which is `featured` with boolean value, and I need to apply `ORDER BY featured DESC` at the beginning of each query with keeping the other `ORDER BY` fields as it is(i.e. popular query should be like this `SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."featured" DESC, "products"."popularity" DESC, "products"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 10`).

**Note:** `ORDER BY featured DESC` is just appended at the beginning of the previous `ORDER BY` statement, and it is applied on the subset not on the whole model.

***What I have tried?***

I have tried the following scenarios:

- Add `@products = @products.order(featured: :desc)` in the controller but the result is not as expected because it adds the order to the end of existing order by chain.
- Use `default_scope` in Product model `default_scope { order(featured: :desc) }` but the result is not as expected because it implements the order on the whole model, but the expected result is applying the order only on the subset(10 records).
- using `reorder` in the controller `@products = @products.reorder('').order(featured: :desc)` but the result still not as expected because this remove the old order and actually I need to keep it but at the end of `ORDER BY` chain

The only solution I'm able to do is by using string variable to save previous order by chain, then use `reorder('').order(featured: :desc)` and finally append the string at the end of new `ORDER BY`:

```
current_order = @products.to_sql[@products.to_sql.downcase.index('order by')+8..@products.to_sql.downcase.index('limit')-1]
@products = @products.reorder("featured desc, #{current_order}" )
```

**But I'm sure there is a better solution which I need your support to achieve it.**

**Summary:**

As summarised in the comments below, I need the following implementation:

Given just `r` where `r = M.order(:a)`, I want to run `r.something(:b)` and get the effect of `M.order(:b).order(:a)` rather than the `M.order(:a).order(:b)` that `r.order(:b)` would give you

Comment: So given just `r` where `r = M.order(:a)` you want to say `r.something(:b)` and get the effect of `M.order(:b).order(:a)` rather than the `M.order(:a).order(:b)` that `r.order(:b)` would give you, right?

Comment: Since there are only 10 records you could sort them in Ruby too with `@products.sort_by(&:featured)`, or am I misunderstanding the output you want perhaps.

Comment: @Iceman `sort_by` result is Array and I'm expecting `ActiveRecord_Relation` and also `sort_by` doesn't work with `boolean`

Comment: Ahh, ok, just an idea, didn't read your question well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're not using `scope` chaining here? This seems like a perfect case to use it in. The use of `enum` is unclear, as well.

Something like this:

```
# /app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 scope :recent, { order(created_at: :desc) }
 scope :cheapest, { order(price: :asc) }
 scope :most_expensive, { order(price: :desc) }
 scope :popular, { order(popularity: :desc) }
 scope :featured, { where(featured: true) }
end
```

Then in your controller you could do:

```
# /app/controllers/products_controller.rb
...
Product.featured.cheapest.limit(10)
Product.featured.most_expensive.limit(10)
...
```

and so on.

AREL should build the query correctly, and IIRC you can swap the sequence of the scopes (`featured` after `cheapest`, for example) if you want them to be applied differently.

Comment: This doesn't help in my scenario, my question is about modifying the `ORDER BY` chain, and need to be implemented on a subset (scoped already) and I need to do it in generic way(not for each category separately).

Comment: You can check @mu_is_too_short comment, it summarizes my question in a pretty & simple way.